# Module filepath from loaded module object

Tags: haskell, module

In python, it is

```
import argparser
print argparser.__file__
```

My questions are:

- How can i do the same in haskell i.e. to get the file location of a module from using loaded module object in haskell?
- In haskell, the library file is in non-readable `.hi` format. Is there a way with `cabal install`, that i can download source files into `~/.cabal` and compile it locally?

Comment: The latter is possible with `cabal get <package>`. But honestly, that's pretty obvious from the documentation of `cabal-install`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but this is how I would find the location of the module in Haskell. Say I have a module named `Data.Text` and I want to find it's location. Then I initially find out it's package name:

```
$ ghc-pkg find-module Data.Text
/nix/store/cq4qqjii3s9ghr6p59kkrdf44wnyhpp4-ghc-7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
/home/sibi/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   text-1.2.0.4
```

Now I know that the package name is `text-1.2.0.4`. So, now all I do is use this command to find the module location:

```
$ ghc-pkg describe text-1.2.0.4   # (Just text should also work)
```

And this will give you a big output. The interested fields for you are `import-dirs` and `library-dirs`.

To find out the source of the installed package, you can use `cabal get <package_name>` as mentioned by @Martin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do the first thing in Haskell. However, if you just want to find out this path for yourself, you can use the command

```
ghc-pkg describe <package>
```

where `<package>` is the name of the package the module belongs to.

For downloading the source code of a package, just use

```
cabal get <package>
```

It will download the sources without any dependencies into a directory `<package>-<version>` within your current directory.